# SQLite adding minute field to date field

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

Let's say i have a simple database like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE test (start TEXT, end TEXT, duration INTEGER);
```

The `start` and `end` are dates and duration is in minutes. I would like to check if start+duration < end

I know i can use the date function `datetime(start,'+14 minutes');` but how would i do that with another column value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a constraint so that `start + duration` is always less than `end` in your table then this is the syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  start TEXT, 
  end TEXT, 
  duration INTEGER,
  CHECK (DATETIME(start, duration || ' minute') < end)
);
```

There is no need to concatenate `'+'`.
This will work only if your date columns have the only valid date format for SQLite which is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.
Note that if the table already exists you can't add the constraint.
You will have to create a new table with the above schema (including the constraint), copy the data of the old table to the new table (if they meet the condition of the constraint), delete the old table and rename the new table.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a string:

```
datetime(start, '+' || dur || ' minute')
```

Answer (score 0):

It this what you want?

```
dt_start < datetime(dt_end, '+' || duration || ' minute')
```

Note that `start` and `end` are language keywords in most databases, hence not good choices for column names. I renamed those columns `dt_start` and `dt_end` in the above code.